# Finding parent caller file, line number, and function in Swift

Tags: swift, exception

I would like to print the caller function but uncertain how to do that. The `#function` gives the current location but consider a general `formatError()` method:

```
static func formatError(_ except: Error) -> String {
    return "[\(tss()) \(#file).\(#line):\(#function)] ERROR: \(except.localizedDescription)"
}
```

The the `#file` `#line` and `#function` only tell us about the `formatError()` helper method - which is not helpful.

```
 /Users/steve/git/cider/native/onsets/onsets/FileUtils.swift.94:formatError(_:)]
```

A solution that works is this:

```
// Helper method
static func formatError(_ file: String, _ line: Int,
    _ function: String, _ except: Error) -> String {
    return "[\(tss()) \(file).\(line):\(function)] ERROR: \(except.localizedDescription)"
}

// Caller
formatError(#file, #line, #function, except)
```

Result:

```
/Users/steve/git/onsets/FileUtils.swift.110:writeFile(subDir:fname:data:)] 
ERROR: The file “samples0514616_5359.dat” doesn’t exist.
```

But it is awkward to send #file, #line, #function, in from the *caller* every time.   Is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use default argument values. It would look something like this:

```swift
func formatError(_ except: Error,
    function: StaticString = #function,
    file: StaticString  = #file,
    line: UInt  = #line) -> String {
    return "[\(file).\(line):\(function)] ERROR: \(except.localizedDescription)"
}
```

Comment: works great - thx!  I did not realize the default parameters would be resolved at the `caller` site -but it makes sense. Also am unfamiliar with `StaticString` and am going to look into that!

Comment: @javadba These `#`-prefixed symbols are special. They're the only caller-side evaluated default params, and they're specifically made so for this purpose.

Comment: @javadba Done! Always annoying when that happens. I really wish you had to provide a reason for a downvote. Thanks for the "heads up"!